# Azure AKS Let's Encrypt - "Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist"

Tags: x509certificate, azure-aks, cert-manager

I have followed Microsoft tutorial to setup inggress but cannot issue valid SSL certificate with cert-manager. Below are describe for `Ingress`, `ClusterIssuer` and `Certificate`. Posted are also created by the cluster issuer, `Order` and 'Challenge`

```html
Name:             erpdeploymenttripletex-ingress
Namespace:        tripletex
Address:          20.223.184.33
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  tls-secret terminates otterlei.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
Rules:
  Host                                     Path  Backends
  ----                                     ----  --------
  otterlei.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
                                           /estataerpiconnectorapi   estataconnservice:80 (10.244.1.150:8080)
                                           /(.*)                     estataconnservice:80 (10.244.1.150:8080)
Annotations:                               acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: true
                                           cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
                                           cert-manager.io/issue-temporary-certificate: true
                                           kubernetes.io/ingress.class: tripletex
                                           meta.helm.sh/release-name: erpideploymenttripletexprod
                                           meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: tripletex
                                           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
                                           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:                                    <none>
```

```html
Name:         letsencrypt-staging
Namespace:    
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"cert-manager.io/v1alpha2","kind":"ClusterIssuer","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"letsencrypt-staging"},"spec":{"acme":...
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         ClusterIssuer
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-03-11T08:31:50Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:acme:
          .:
          f:email:
          f:privateKeySecretRef:
            .:
            f:name:
          f:server:
          f:solvers:
    Manager:      kubectl.exe
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-03-11T08:31:50Z
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:acme:
          .:
          f:lastRegisteredEmail:
        f:conditions:
    Manager:      controller
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-03-11T08:31:51Z
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:acme:
          f:uri:
    Manager:         controller
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2022-03-14T13:23:16Z
  Resource Version:  192224854
  UID:               5ef69bfc-f3a9-4bd2-8520-e390adbd1763
Spec:
  Acme:
    Email:            penko.yordanov@icb.bg
    Preferred Chain:  
    Private Key Secret Ref:
      Name:  letsencrypt-staging
    Server:  https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    Solvers:
      http01:
        Ingress:
          Class:  nginx
          Pod Template:
            Metadata:
            Spec:
              Node Selector:
                kubernetes.io/os:  linux
Status:
  Acme:
    Last Registered Email:  penko.yordanov@icb.bg
    Uri:                    https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/47169398
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-03-11T08:31:51Z
    Message:               The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                ACMEAccountRegistered
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

```html
Name:         tls-secret
Namespace:    tripletex
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"cert-manager.io/v1","kind":"Certificate","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"tls-secret","namespace":"tripletex"},"spec":{...
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-03-16T09:37:39Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
    Manager:      controller
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-03-16T09:37:39Z
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:nextPrivateKeySecretName:
    Manager:      controller
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-03-16T09:37:39Z
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:dnsNames:
        f:issuerRef:
          .:
          f:group:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
        f:secretName:
    Manager:         kubectl.exe
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2022-03-16T09:37:39Z
  Resource Version:  193021094
  UID:               e1da4438-952b-4df0-a141-1a3d29e5e9b9
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    otterlei.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:      cert-manager.io
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-staging
  Secret Name:  tls-secret
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2022-03-16T09:37:39Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      False
    Type:                        Ready
    Last Transition Time:        2022-03-16T09:37:39Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  tls-secret-kxkhf
Events:                          <none>
```

`Order`

```html
Name:         tls-secret-fxpxl-1057960237
Namespace:    tripletex
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/certificate-name: tls-secret
              cert-manager.io/certificate-revision: 1
              cert-manager.io/private-key-secret-name: tls-secret-kxkhf
              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"cert-manager.io/v1","kind":"Certificate","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"tls-secret","namespace":"tripletex"},"spec":{...
API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Order
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-03-16T09:37:40Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:finalizeURL:
        f:state:
        f:url:
    Manager:      controller
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-03-16T09:37:40Z
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:authorizations:
    Manager:    controller
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2022-03-16T09:37:40Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           cert-manager.io/v1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  CertificateRequest
    Name:                  tls-secret-fxpxl
    UID:                   6ec06c5a-8bd7-49a0-90a5-7d71b796f236
  Resource Version:        193021106
  UID:                     50539071-d3ed-4d79-a2f6-6fcc79f0d41b
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    otterlei.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:  cert-manager.io
    Kind:   ClusterIssuer
    Name:   letsencrypt-staging
  Request:  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
Status:
  Authorizations:
    Challenges:
      Token:        W7zdK6beQBcAPTSTrc_6Mv_wiDknSgh3i1XKb617Nos
      Type:         http-01
      URL:          https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/1913552008/KocZGw
      Token:        W7zdK6beQBcAPTSTrc_6Mv_wiDknSgh3i1XKb617Nos
      Type:         dns-01
      URL:          https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/1913552008/x0hWcg
      Token:        W7zdK6beQBcAPTSTrc_6Mv_wiDknSgh3i1XKb617Nos
      Type:         tls-alpn-01
      URL:          https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/1913552008/Hidh4g
    Identifier:     otterlei.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    Initial State:  pending
    URL:            https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/1913552008
    Wildcard:       false
  Finalize URL:     https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/finalize/47169398/2042532738
  State:            pending
  URL:              https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/47169398/2042532738
Events:             <none>
```

`challenge`

```html
Name:         tls-secret-fxpxl-1057960237-691767986
Namespace:    tripletex
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Challenge
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-03-16T09:37:40Z
  Finalizers:
    finalizer.acme.cert-manager.io
  Generation:  1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:finalizers:
          .:
          v:"finalizer.acme.cert-manager.io":
        f:ownerReferences:
          .:
          k:{"uid":"50539071-d3ed-4d79-a2f6-6fcc79f0d41b"}:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:authorizationURL:
        f:dnsName:
        f:issuerRef:
          .:
          f:group:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
        f:key:
        f:solver:
          .:
          f:http01:
            .:
            f:ingress:
              .:
              f:class:
              f:podTemplate:
                .:
                f:metadata:
                f:spec:
                  .:
                  f:nodeSelector:
                    .:
                    f:kubernetes.io/os:
        f:token:
        f:type:
        f:url:
        f:wildcard:
    Manager:    controller
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2022-03-16T09:37:40Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Order
    Name:                  tls-secret-fxpxl-1057960237
    UID:                   50539071-d3ed-4d79-a2f6-6fcc79f0d41b
  Resource Version:        193021107
  UID:                     665341e0-2745-48c2-a985-166e58646d44
Spec:
  Authorization URL:  https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/1913552008
  Dns Name:           otterlei.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:  cert-manager.io
    Kind:   ClusterIssuer
    Name:   letsencrypt-staging
  Key:      W7zdK6beQBcAPTSTrc_6Mv_wiDknSgh3i1XKb617Nos.PeCQyw56kTw4k7brocD-LfWP2NllTueut46pJ7EU2yw
  Solver:
    http01:
      Ingress:
        Class:  nginx
        Pod Template:
          Metadata:
          Spec:
            Node Selector:
              kubernetes.io/os:  linux
  Token:                         W7zdK6beQBcAPTSTrc_6Mv_wiDknSgh3i1XKb617Nos
  Type:                          HTTP-01
  URL:                           https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/1913552008/KocZGw
  Wildcard:                      false
Events:                          <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

The message "Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist" is ok as the secret with the cert does not exist.

Can you try this config:

Cluster issuer:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    email: EMAIL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: issuer-key
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: YOUR_URL
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: DEMO
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - YOUR_URL
    secretName: YOUR_URL
```

Comment: Tried this solution but still SSL is not valid!

Comment: can you show the logs of the cert-manager pod?